# JWT authorization using Axios post request

Tags: javascript, rest, post, jwt

I received a JWT which I stored locally. Using this same JWT, I am attempting to make a POST request, however I am getting an 401 error, and an error which says "No JWT provided". I know that the JWT is valid as I have used it in my GET requests successfully.

```
axios
    .post("https://example.com", {
      headers: {
        token:
          "abc"
      },
      solutions: {
        solution: answer
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
};
```

Edit:
I am adding the code for my GET request that works as a reference.

```
axios
  .get("https://example.com", {
    headers: {
      token:
        "abc"
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // makeResponse(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `headers: {
        token` - does the server look for the JWT in a header called token? Is the server your server?

Comment: @Bravo the server does look for the JWT in a header called token. It is not my server, but a commercial server. I have made GET requests using the same format with a successful result, but my POST requests aren't working.

Comment: so, you've made GET requests with the JWT token in the `token` header, and that's where it needs to be for GET requests?

Comment: @Bravo yeah, thats right. The API I am using specifies that I need to attach a JWT to a header called "token" for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `axios.post` can take in 3 arguments. The first one is the endpoint, second is the payload, and the third is the config or where your token is stored.

`axios.post(endpoint, payload, config)`

I think you have it set in the wrong order:

```
axios
    .post("https://example.com", {
      headers: {
        token:
          "abc"
      },
      solutions: {
        solution: answer
      }
    })
```

this should be:

```
axios
    .post("https://example.com", 
      solutions: {
        solution: answer
      },
      {
         headers: {
           token: "abc"
         }
      }
     )
```

Comment: Yep, this was my problem. Thank you!